# Finitely additive measure on $\mathbb R$

Tags: measure-theory

Suppose $\mathcal B$ is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb R$. Let $\mu : \mathcal B \rightarrow [0, \infty ]$ be a finitely additive(but not necessarily countably additive), translation-invariant, ''measure'', with the property that $\mu(K) < \infty$ for every compact $K \subset \mathbb R $.

Let $P(\mathbb R)$ denote the power set of $\mathbb R$.

Does there exist a finitely additive, translation-invariant "measure", $\tilde \mu : P(\mathbb R) \rightarrow [0, \infty ]$, extending $\mu$ ?

In particular, let $\mu$ be the Lebesgue measure on the Borel $\sigma$-algebra. Can something be said about this special case at least?

Comment: Just because I'm feeling a real wise guy right now, and it needs to be said, in certain models where the axiom of choice fails it is consistent that the Lebesgue measure is such extension of the Borel measure (i.e. translation invariant, countably additive, all sets are measurable, compact sets have finite measure). But all that is all and well without the axiom of choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know about the general case. But [here](http://books.google.nl/books?id=4_wqWCfZCA0C&pg=PA38&lpg=PA38&dq=finitely%20additive%20measure%20on%20power%20set%20of%20reals%20translation%20invariant&source=bl&ots=nCX1If3M6o&sig=zECWe_vKWEqVFL_DOCk9Y2FV02c&hl=nl&sa=X&ei=AeCRUaOcLYKg0wX3yYCICw&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=finitely%20additive%20measure%20on%20power%20set%20of%20reals%20translation%20invariant&f=false) Tao states that the Lebesgue case is true, using the Hahn-Banach theorem.

Comment: Ah, thanks. This is helpful to know.